# grails: where can utility code be placed, that doesn't cause a container restart?

Tags: grails

I'm wondering where utility code can be placed, that doesn't cause a restart of container. Updating controllers doesn't cause a container restart & the updated code is available to run (great), but I wanted a more general library/utility place for my utility code.

Putting the code in /utils or in src/groovy does cause a restart on save, at least using Intellij, but I imagine this is the same regardless of where Grails is developed.

Perhaps you have some general info/insights on how Grails does this -- includes new code but doesn't need to restart the container, if that's only special to controllers?

(v. 1.3.7)

Comment: Interesting question... there is a page on the Grails documentation but it needs some love (it is three years old): http://www.grails.org/Auto+Reloading

Comment: Did you already give the new Grails 2.0.M2 a try? It comes with a new JVM agent to handle reloading of changed classes and so no container restart is required.

Comment: No, I'm doing a production release so didn't want to go to 2.0 yet, and haven't had time to try it.  Thanks for pointing this out, I'll look forward to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're out of luck out of the box unless you want to use 2.0.  The alternative is to turn off auto-reloading and add in something like jrebel.  See this [blog](http://arhipov.blogspot.com/2010/08/having-fun-with-grails-and-jrebel.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks Gregg.  I think I'll keep the utility code in a controller class near term then, until I upgrade to 2.0.  Weird though, am currently updating a Controller's code -- adding something as simple as a println, and no changes come out, even though I know the method is getting hit (as it has another println in it at the end).  Am using Intellij.